# How to present a UIPopoverPresentationController in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to present a UIPopoverPresentationController in SpriteKit but I am struggling to find out how to do it. How can I do this in SpriteKit?

Comment: Are you just looking for something to pop up on your screen?  Easiest thing to do is break your scene up,  something like Scene->MainNode-> all your nodes, then Scene->PopupNode->all nodes in popup,  this way the popup is always on top of main.  You could also just add the pop up node to your existing setup with a very high z index

Comment: The reason @Knight0fDragon is suggesting this - UIKit over the top of SKViews kills performance, even on the latest and greatest Apple devices.

Comment: @Confused, The reason I am suggesting this is because popping a node on top of a SKScene is the easiest way to get a pop up on the screen.  When developing your apps if you want to go ahead and alienate the older devices be my guest. You can write your own performance tests to see the performance issues you get when mixing UIKit and Sprite Kit.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the performance problems. I'm trying to point out that Apple does their best to encourage people to use UIViews over the top of an SKView. Most people coming to Sprite Kit are going to read that apple literature and have no idea it's a bad idea to blend these frameworks.

Comment: You're doing a service to Onglo (and new users) by telling him this, but he's not going to realise why you're saying this because until you've mentioned it, he thinks these frameworks are meant to play together because that's how Apple presents them. All puns intended.

Comment: Be nice if Apple was open and honest about the limitations of their frameworks, though.

Comment: @Confused Ahh I misinterpreted what you were saying,  my apologies,  yes, unfortunately Apple does not go over when you should and should not be mixing UIKit and SpriteKit,  and a lot of Sprite Kit in itself seems rushed, with poor documentation to boot compared to UI Kit